# What is the suitable .htaccess rewriterule for my website

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2.4

I think I don't understand exactly how .htaccess rewrite work, so I am asking for your help. I need to change http://www.mywebsite.com/index.php?name=first to http://www.mywebsite.com/first . 
Is this possible?
My current .htaccess file's content is:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /index.php?menu=$1 [L]
```

Obviously it's not working. What would the .htaccess file's content be?

Comment: You should also [check to see if your `.htacess` file is loaded](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/htaccess.html#when). And if you have root access consider [not using a `.htacess` file at all](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/htaccess.html#when)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't u use this in your .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule 
^(.*)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

Then in your index.php you return the appropriate page:

```
# SELECT WHICH PAGE TO DISPLAY
function getPage($showPage) {
    $modules = array(#never name the slugs as same as the php pages
    '/sign-in/i' => 'register.php',
    '/signout/i' => 'logout.php',
    '/staff/i' => 'admin.php',
    '/products/i' => 'blank.php',
    );
    foreach ($modules as $slug=>$phpmodule) {
        if(preg_match($slug, $showPage)) { 
            return $phpmodule;
        }
    } 
    return 'blank.php';#in case module not found display 404 page
}

if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
require_once (getPage($_GET['page'])); #include the appropriate module file
}
```

There's so many ways you could do it. I hope this gives you an idea where you can start, and if my answer's been of use to you please vote up or accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Options All -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?name=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Another little thing... Most of the times there is only this variable(name), but sometimes I have another variable (index.php?name=$1&var=$2). How can I 'say' to .htaccess when to look for one and when for two variables?

Answer (score 0):

Just put this in your .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule 
^(.*)/?$ index.php?name=$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: For more variables try this:RewriteRule ^browse/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ ?page=browser&make=$1&ser=$2 [NC,L]

Comment: In your case: RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?&name=$1&var=$2 [NC,L]
Does this help you?

Comment: Most of the times there is only this variable(name), but sometimes I have another variable (index.php?name=$1&var=$2). How can I 'say' to .htaccess when to look for one and when for two variables?